# Method for struct itself in Go

Tags: go, go-gorm

I noticed that in the ORM library Gorm, you can define a custom table name using a structure like below:

```
type DeviceStatus struct {
  // Define some Gorm model fields here
}

// TableName custumizes DeviceStatus SQL table name
func (DeviceStatus) TableName() string {
    return "CustomDeviceStatusTableName"
}
```

What is this construct called? I'm trying to find this with Google and figure out how to do a function call.

Comment: I don't know gorm, but it looks like if a type implements the interface that has the method `TableName() string`, then it uses  that interface to get the table name.

Comment: That is correct. The question is about when I'm trying to implement my own method. The method is not a regular struct method nor a struct pointer method. I want to know the name of this construct.

Comment: Or is it just a regular struct method? It's just that there is no variable defined I find it weird.

Comment: It is a method of DeviceStatus. Since there is no need for a receiver, it is not declared.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thanks, that clarifies it.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations:  *"If the receiver's value is not referenced inside the body of the method, its identifier may be omitted in the declaration. The same applies in general to parameters of functions and methods. "*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right, it implements the interface, and gorm will get the table name from TableName() method and struct name instead if TableName() is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing the [`tabler`](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/7180bd0f27d167f18c253c32d548c7de3adc6b0d/scope.go#L305) interface. It contains only one method:

```
type tabler interface {
    TableName() string
}
```

Read more about [Interface types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) in the specs.